# Using Javascript how would I deconstruct and reconstruct this array of objects to json objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Basically how do I convert this:

```
files = [
 { 
   transformation: 't_16x9_lg',
   width: 1920,
   height: 1080,
   bytes: 633634,
   format: 'jpg',
   url: 'xxx.png'
 },
 { 
   transformation: 't_16x9_md',
   width: 1440,
   height: 810,
   bytes: 383730,
   format: 'jpg',
    url: 'xxx.png'
 }
]
```

To this:

```
files = { 
  't_16x9_lg': { 
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    bytes: 633634,
    format: 'jpg',
    url: 'xxx.png'
  },
  't_16x9_md': {
    width: 1440,
    height: 810,
    bytes: 383730,
    format: 'jpg',
    url: 'xxx.png'
  }
}
```

Stack overflow is asking me to add more details but not sure what else to add here. I guess just ask if you need more details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could destructure `transformation` and build new objects.

```js
var files = [{ transformation: 't_16x9_lg', width: 1920, height: 1080, bytes: 633634, format: 'jpg', url: 'xxx.png' }, { transformation: 't_16x9_md', width: 1440, height: 810, bytes: 383730, format: 'jpg', url: 'xxx.png' }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(
        files.map(({ transformation, ...object }) => [transformation, object])
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Turns out I actually tried this earlier and many/100s of other things and nothing was working. Turns out I was using an old version of node 10.x so anything es6 related (fromEntries, spread) was the issue. Upgraded node to 12.x and all works now.